# Remove certain pattern from text using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
text = "Page 1 of 28 Medical Policies Archived Policies - Radiology Print Percutaneous Balloon Kyphoplasty, Radiofrequency Kyphoplasty, and Mechanical  Page 2/3 Percutaneous radiofrequency kyphoplasty or percutaneous mechanical vertebral augmentation using any other device, including but not limited. Page 38 Percutaneous Balloon Kyphoplasty, Radiofrequency Kyphoplasty, and Me... While radiotherapy and chemotherapy are frequently "

adm = re.sub("(?:(?:Page" [0-9] "of" [0-9] | Page [0-9] |  Page [0-9] "/" [0-9] ))", text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(adm)
```

Is there any solution to remove Page 1 of 28 , Page 2/3 , Page 38 from the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this approach:

```py
text = "Page 1 of 28 Medical Policies Archived Policies - Radiology Print Percutaneous Balloon Kyphoplasty, Radiofrequency Kyphoplasty, and Mechanical  Page 2/3 Percutaneous radiofrequency kyphoplasty or percutaneous mechanical vertebral augmentation using any other device, including but not limited. Page 38 Percutaneous Balloon Kyphoplasty, Radiofrequency Kyphoplasty, and Me... While radiotherapy and chemotherapy are frequently "
output = re.sub(r'\s*Page \d+(?:/\d+)?(?: of \d+)?\s*', ' ', text).strip()
print(output)
```

This prints:

> Medical Policies Archived Policies - Radiology Print Percutaneous Balloon Kyphoplasty, Radiofrequency Kyphoplasty, and Mechanical Percutaneous radiofrequency kyphoplasty or percutaneous mechanical vertebral augmentation using any other device, including but not limited. Percutaneous Balloon Kyphoplasty, Radiofrequency Kyphoplasty, and Me... While radiotherapy and chemotherapy are frequently

The regex pattern used above matches all 3 page variants seen in `Page 1 of 28 , Page 2/3 , Page 38`.

Answer (score 0):

a simple correction of your work

```
remove_pages=re.compile("(?:(?:Page [0-9] of [0-9]{1,2} | Page [0-9]{1,2} |  Page [0-9]/[0-9] ))", re.IGNORECASE)
adm = re.sub(remove_pages, '', text)
```

sometimes you were matching for one number when you wanted to catch two. you added spaces between the slash. you forgot the replacement string for `sub`. you can't add flags in `sub`